# Routing from one router to another?

Tags: routing, router, pfsense, routes

I'm trying to route from one basic router to a pfsense box. It's basically so that I can have VPN users on both router aswell as VPN tunnels to test which router performs best. I am also trying to segregate the network with VLANS and the existing router doesn't perform this job very well.

At the moment the network looks like this:

```
Draytek (existing router)
192.168.1.99
Network is 192.168.1.0/24

LAN port connected to WAN port on new router


pfSense (new router)
10.1.1.1
Network is 10.1.1.0/24
WAN port of this router has an IP of 192.168.1.115
```

I've set routes up on both routers. On the existing router I have the following:

```
10.1.1.0/24 routes to gateway IP address 192.168.1.115.
```

On the new router I have the static routes of:

```
192.168.1.0/24 routes to gateway IP address 192.168.1.99
```

Routing is not working between them, am I doing something obviously wrong. I think it's a case of not seeing the wood for the trees.

Neither router can ping the other at all.

Comment: the Draytek (from what you've described) isn't acting as a router since it is only connected to 1 network (192.168.1.0/24)

Comment: You don't need a route on the pfsense for 192.168.1.0/24 as the WAN interface is already on that network. Have you enabled ping on the WAN interface? What is the general FW setup. I would expect the WAN to be blocking most traffic by default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well for a start why would the pFsense route through the draytek if it is directly connected to (192.168.1.0)? You need 3 networks, 1 behind each router, and the third in the middle where they will talk.

Comment: Don't worry, I know by having done these sort of things myself :)

Answer (score 0):

if the pfsense is getting it's IP (1.115) from the Draytek (1.99), and the 10.x.x.x is only a DHCP pool issued from pfsense, you probably won't be able to reroute to 1.115 since it is itself.